# About issuing token on private ethereum chain (POA Consensus )

Tags: tokens

I'm trying to create a private POA ETH chain and then issue my own token on it.

I have some questions about how to make the whole system work.

The one question is that after I have a private chain and before set up smart contract to issue token, how can I dig out all the coins in advance?

Another one is how to set the total coin number of private chain?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In geth version of PoA "Clique" you set the total of coins in the genesis blocks and no other coins will be mined ever.

Validators get the transaction fee, but there's no reward for block creation.

Comment: what do you mean by "set the total of coins in the genesis blocks"?  is it referring to allocate total amount of ether to my defined account in genesis file? and how to know and where to set total amount of ethers in Clique poa private chain?

Comment: Yes, you assign to an one or several accounts the balance you want in the genesis block. You can use a tool like puppeth to generate the correct genesis file.

Comment: I see. then how can I define the maximum Ether coin number as bitcoin has 210,000,000 coins. thanks.

Comment: Ether uses 18 decimals, and bitcoin has a supply of 21,000,000 bitcoins. So you have to assign `21000000 * 10^18 = 21000000000000000000000000`.

Comment: Get confused, Why is the total amount of ether coins related to bitcoin's supply? and What's the unit of  "21000000 * 10^18"? Wei or Ether? thanks.

Comment: 1. In a previous comment you said that want to define "the maximum Ether coin number as bitcoin has 210,000,000", and that number is incorrect the total supply of bitcoins is 21,000,000. 2.The unit used in the genesis file is wei.

Comment: sorry for my unclear statement, I mean how to define the max value of total supply of Ether coin,  because bitcoin has the supply limit value, I want to know how to set it in Ethereum too.:)

Comment: Ethereum doesn't have a way to set the total supply in PoW. But in PoA you can assign the full amount to addresses you control, this work because PoA doesn't have block rewards so new coins are not created after the genesis block.